# how to couple 'reasons' with return values, elegantly

Tags: python

What often happens in code I'm writing is I'll have a function that checks a condition dependent on many other conditions, e.g.:

```
def is_foo(bar):
    if X: return True
    if Y: return False
    if Z: return True
    return False
```

Then, I'll want to debug my code or log it, so I'll change the above to:

```
def is_foo_reason(bar):
    if X: return True, "cause of X you fool"
    if Y: return False, "no X but Y"
    if Z: return True, "Z Z Z Z Z Z"
    return False, "default"
#for backwards compatibility:
def is_foo(bar): return is_foo_reason(bar)[0]
```

Then the code that wants the reason (so it can log it / show it to user, w/e) calls the `_reason` version.

My question is: is there any more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

This is a perfectly good way to do it. Only thing I might change is nest `is_foo_reason` in `is_foo` (so that there's only one, simple interface) and add a default argument to `is_foo()`, e.g.

```
#for backwards compatibility:
def is_foo(bar, reason=False): 
    def is_foo_reason(bar):
        if X: return True, "cause of X you fool"
        if Y: return False, "no X but Y"
        if Z: return True, "Z Z Z Z Z Z"
        return False, "default"
    if reason:
        return is_foo_reason(bar)
    else:
        return is_foo_reason(bar)[0]
```

That way, the function by default won't give a reason, but if you want one, you can ask for one.

Comment: +1 I've done something similar, when for validation, where sometimes I just want to know if something is valid, and other times I want the error to show to the user.

Comment: hmm interesting. i was worried about having different return types but if its entirely dependent upon the parameter then this makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 4):

I think you shouldn't change the semantics of your function(s) if it's just about debugging. Use e.g. a logger instead. Take a look at Python's logging module: http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html

```
import logging

def is_foo(bar):
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    if X:
        logger.debug("msg1")
        return True
    if Y:
        logger.debug("msg2")
        ...
```

Then you can define your logging handler to either log the messages to a file, or print them on the screen, etc.

Comment: But if you want to show it to the user, as OP said, logging doesn't work.

Comment: Why not? You can use StreamHandler and provide sys.stdout as stream, or am I missing something?

Comment: if i want to pop up a dialog to display it, or send the reason to a DB, or to a webpage, or whatnot. need the string value. this is probably the best answer for logging though

Answer (score 1):

For future extensibility of your return values, use a namedtuple:

```
from collections import namedtuple
ExplainedValue = namedtuple('ExplainedValue', 'value explanation')

def is_foo_reason(bar):
    if X: return ExplainedValue(True, "cause of X you fool")
    if Y: return ExplainedValue(False, "no X but Y")
    if Z: return ExplainedValue(True, "Z Z Z Z Z Z")
    return ExplainedValue(False, "default")

def is_foo(bar): return is_foo_reason(bar).value
```